# join operation in ruby on rails for multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

There are three tables in my postgresql database named  "audits","locations","companies".

I want want to retrieve data by joining these tables.I have an executable sql query which gives my expected result.I want to convert this into ruby on rails.

```
select a.name as cname, b.name as lname, count(c.company_id) as count
from companies as a, locations as b, audits as c
where a.id=c.company_id and b.id =c.location_id
group by a.name,b.name;
```

Comment: [find_by_sql](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to recreate you models from your query ( I might get it wrong, so you should paste that along your query too):

```
class Company
  has_many :locations
  has_many :audits
end

class Location
  belongs_to :company
  has_many   :audits
end

class Audit
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :location
end
```

So to recreate your query do:

```
Company.joins(:locations, :audits)
  .group("companies.name", "locations.name")
  .count("audits.company_id")
```

The result will he a hash where the key is an array consisting of company_name and location_name and the value is the count like this:

```
{[company_name, location_name] => count, ...}
```

This will result in the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(audits.company_id) AS count_audits_company_id, companies.name AS companies_name, locations.name AS locations_name 
FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."company_id" = "companies"."id"
INNER JOIN "audits" ON "audits"."company_id" = "companies"."id" 
GROUP BY companies.name, locations.name
```

More info [count](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count)